# AngularJS ng-keyup fired twice

Tags: angularjs

My input `ng-keyup` always fires twice, but other events like `ng-click` etc... are fine.

```
<div id="pageContent" ng-controller="moduleController" ng-cloak>
    <div class="row note-list" ng-if="showList">
        <input id="search" ng-keyup="test()" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div class="col-12" ng-repeat="note in notes" ng-click="editNote(note.id)">
            <p class="note-list-title">{{note.title}}</p>
            <p class="note-list-date">{{note.dateCreated | displayDate}}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-click="newNote()" class="add-btn btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showList" class="note-editor">
        <div>
            <div ng-click="back()" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></div>
            <div ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></div>
        </div>
        <h1 contenteditable="true" id="title">{{selected.title}}</h1>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="note-container" ng-bind-html="selected.note" id="note"style="white-space: pre-line;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    app.controller('moduleController', moduleController);

    function moduleController($scope, $http, $window) {
        ......

        $scope.test = function() {
            console.log("TEST");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Why is this happening? What are the possible cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

One approach to debugging problems with event handlers is to look at the `$event` object:

```html
<input ng-keyup="test($event)">
```

```js
$scope.test = function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
};
```

Directives like `ngClick` and `ngFocus` expose a `$event` object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)